# Yahtzee where to 6’s near end of game

Tags: yahtzee

It’s near the end of the game but I still don’t have 6’s, my bonus or a Yahtzee.  I roll all 6’s for a Yahtzee.  I’m reluctant to put that in the Yahtzee slot because I need at least four 6’s to get the bonus.

When this happens, and it’s happened to me a few times, why not put the Yahtzee in the 6’s?  That way, I get 65 points as opposed to 50 (30 for the 6’s, 35 for the bonus).

Comment: It sounds like you're asking "why not *make the best play*?" And I don't have a good answer for that.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that it is the second last round, you can expect about 1 point more by going with 6s.

In case you go for yahtzee you get 50 points now and expect about 16.3 points including a bonus for 4 sixes or more in the last round for a total of 66.3 points.
In case you go for 6s you get 65 points now and expect about 2.4 points for yahtzee in the last round.

If 3 sixes were enough to get the bonus you should go for yahtzee instead.

Comment: Note that it does matter how many points you need/want though. The expected average isn't all that matters; if you need exactly 66 or 67 points in order to win or reach your goal; then taking the Yahtzee now becomes better.